# gravity forms querystrings in email

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have two gravity forms on my website that pass the email parameter via query strings. However, an email is sent to the user after he/she submits form one. In that email, I would like to have the url with the query string there so that the user can click on it. Whenever I try to do this by appending the mergetag to the end of the url, it never functions.....I am doing something like this www.mywebsite.com/new_form_page/?email={mergetag_email}. Is there a proper way to get this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the issue. Wordpress removes formatting so all I had to do was click the box next to disable formatting and it worked fine....